# punctuation mark should be placed after the end of math mode

Tags: math-mode, lacheck

When writing `there are $n!$ possible permutations of $n$ objects`, lacheck complains that "punctuation mark should be placed after the end of math mode".

Why is this, and how should I do this properly?

Comment: Because `lacheck` doesn't know mathematics. The factorial sign is not punctuation; just ignore the warning.

Comment: Or don't run `lacheck`, then there is no warning to ignore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get rid of this warning for the factorial sign, then you can hide it via a macro or by adding a space or a pair of curly braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\fac}{!}
\begin{document}
there are $n\fac$ or $n! $ or $n!{}$ possible permutations of $n$ objects
\end{document}
```

Then `lacheck` does not complain.

Comment: `!` is classified as a Closing atom (mathcode `"5021`), so using `{!}` might be wrong in other contexts.

Comment: @egreg: There might be a space, if the atom before is a `\mathinner`. Therefore I have fixed the example by putting an empty math atom after the factorial sign. There is no space between a closing and ordinary math atom.